# How to map mutliple keys to a button in Half Life 2/Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, half-life-2

I'm sick of trying to get my rocket jumps accurate enough to actually jump places, that I'm left trying to jump instead of killing the enemy.

This would be helpful in Half Life 2 too. As they have the same engine, doing something in one should be the same in the other, right?

How can I bind a series of keys to a single button?

Comment: Try, try and try again. Building skill need time and patience. Scripting is not satisfying as learning to do manually.

Comment: I take it you mean Half-Life 2. Half-Life and Team Fortress 2 don't share the same engine. TF2 has the same engine as HL2, the Source engine. Half-Life, and Team Fortress Classic, use the GoldSrc engine. Just so you know.

Comment: Sorry, it was neigh on 6am when I posted that. I thought HL was synonymous with HL2. Altered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an **alias**.  Create a file called autoexec.cfg in your Steam\steamapps\YOUR_ALIAS_HERE\team fortress 2\tf\cfg and add the following:

```
//Rocket Jump
alias +rocketjump "+jump;+duck;wait;+attack"
alias -rocketjump "-jump;-attack;wait;wait;wait;-duck"
bind mouse2 "+rocketjump"
```

Change **mouse2** to your desired key.  You can do so much with scripting, this is just one example.  Check out the [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting) for more.

Comment: Since this is a soldier-specific script, you might consider storing this in soldier.cfg (which executes every time you choose Soldier during a game) rather than autoexec.cfg (which executes every time you change classes).

Answer (score 1):

## Simple.

in steam right-click on tf2, press "OPTIONS", click on **Set Launch Options** then type `-console`. Start TF2, press <kbd><sub>`</sub><sup>~</sup></kbd>then type

`alias +hop "+jump;+duck;wait;+attack"`<kbd>↵</kbd>

---

`alias -hop "-jump;-attack;wait;wait;wait;-duck"`<kbd>↵</kbd>

---

`bind`<kbd>Keytobind</kbd> `"+hop""-hop"`

Comment: I do not recommend storing gameplay scripts in launch options. There are class-specific configuration files for this purpose.

Comment: @AustinMohr It's not being set in launch options. The launch option is just to enable the console.

Comment: My mistake. In that case, I believe one can enable the developer console from the Advanced Options menu in-game.

Comment: @AustinMohr I dd know that but for me when I do it that way it is unreliable, so I just did it this way.