# How can I bind keys in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to map keys in Half Life 2/Team Fortress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400/how-to-map-keys-in-half-life-2-team-fortress)

How can I bind keys in Team Fortress 2? I tried to Google it, but I can't find any results I can understand (because I am not English).

Comment: Is there something wrong with Options > Keyboard?

Comment: I'm one of those F2P newbies and was wondering why this question is tagged with `cheat`... Are custom key bindings considered cheating in the TF2 community?

Comment: @chands: Nope, it was incorrectly tagged

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened.  The question this is a supposed "dupe" of concerns mapping multiple actions to a single keypress.  This question is a simple question asking about binding keys, not creating aliases for them

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `bind <key> <command>` in console.  If you were trying to bind the '[' key to 'kill', you could do `bind [ kill`.  If you tell us what you're trying to bind, we can be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the sintax, there is a list somewhere for the commands?

Comment: @Pizzirani There sure is: http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console_Command_List - although you may prefer a version shortened to the most useful ones: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_useful_console_commands